# AWS RDS master password resets every 2 days

Tags: django, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I am very new at aws services. I recently deployed a django application on elasticbeanstalk with aws rds (postgresql). But the master password resets in every 2 days and I can't seem to find a solution for it. This is the error I receive after 2 days of resetting manually.

FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Was it configured to use secrets manager for it's credentials? Also is the RDS application part of the Elastic Beanstalk?

Comment: @ChrisWilliams No it isn't configured to use secrets manager. And I created a db instance on rds and used its credentials in my django app which is deployed on ebs.

Comment: In CloudTrail (make sure you're in the correct region), check for EventName of "ModifyDBInstance". This might indicate what resource is triggering this.

Comment: CloudTrail shows "ModifyDBInstance" only when I did it. Like if I reset it right now manually it will show in CloudTrail and everything will work fine till tomorrow and then it will again say password authentication failed for user "postgres" and nothing on the CloudTrail

Comment: your db instance isn't externally accessible, is it?

Comment: public accessibility is turned on in it

Comment: Have you enabled RDS logging? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_LogAccess.Concepts.PostgreSQL.html. This might help to identify when/whats happening.

Comment: On a sidenote, might also be worth making an app user for the app that does not have DCL permissions, and making rds private

Comment: still cannot figure anything out..

Comment: I have same issue. There are various complaints of this happening but no answers.

Answer (score 0):

The RDS password doesn't reset automatically. You should be having some automated process running that should be resetting this.
You can't recover a password, the only way is to reset the password. Be careful when the password is reset and applied immediately, the RDS goes to maintenance mode.
Try checking the RDS logs - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_LogAccess.Concepts.PostgreSQL.html